# Testing a 4-bit adder

Tags: logic, verilog, addition, hdl

I am trying to make a 4-bit adder and test it. I decided to use `wait` to determine when the adder circuit is done by checking when my `sum` and `carry_out` are >= 0. The inputs for the circuit are given as command line arguments. I am constructing my 4-bit adder using my full adder which I was able test successfully using this method.

### full_adder.v

```
//Behavioral Verilog
module full_adder (input a, input b, input cin, output s, output cout);
    assign s = a ^ b ^ cin;
    assign cout = (a && b) || (a && cin) || (b && cin);
endmodule
```

### 4_bit_adder.v

```
module four_bit_adder(input [0:3] x, input [0:3] y, input carry_in, output [0:3] sum, output carry_out);
    full_adder add1(x[0], y[0], sum[0], carry_in, carry1);
    full_adder add2(x[1], y[1], sum[1], carry1, carry2);
    full_adder add3(x[2], y[2], sum[2], carry2, carry3);
    full_adder add4(x[3], y[3], sum[3], carry3, carry_out);
endmodule
```

### 4_bit_adder_tester.v

```
module four_bit_adder_test;
    reg [0:3]x;
    reg [0:3]y;
    reg carry_in;
    wire sum;
    wire carry_out;
    four_bit_adder adder(x, y, carry_in, sum, carry_out);

    initial begin
        $display("Here");
        if (!$value$plusargs("x=%d", x)) begin
            $display("ERROR: please specify +x=<value> to start.");
            $finish;
        end   
        if (!$value$plusargs("y=%d", y)) begin
            $display("ERROR: please specify +y=<value> to start.");
            $finish;
        end
        if (!$value$plusargs("carry_in=%d", carry_in)) begin
            $display("ERROR: please specify +carry_in=<value> to start.");
            $finish;
        end
        wait(sum >= 0 && carry_out>= 0) $display("sum=%d, carry_out=%d", sum, carry_out);
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

The problem is that `carry_out` remains at `x` so the `sum` and `carry_out` variables never get printed. I tried printing out the value of `carry_out`, and I think the logic in my circuits should work. Is this a valid way of testing my Verilog code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That not a recommended way of testing because you get no output if the data is incorrect.

A better way is checking if the output matches what you expect

```
   $display("Expected %b + %b + %b = %b", x,y,carry_in, {x+y+carry_in});
   #1 // let output propagate
      if ( {carry_out,sum} == x + y + carry_in )
        $display("passed sum=%b, carry_out=%b", sum, carry_out);
      else
        $display("failed sum=%b, carry_out=%b", sum, carry_out);

    end
```

This gives you a better picture of what is going wrong. You sill see that the output is `z` which means you have not connected thing up properly.

Also, get rid of all warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay close attention to your simulator log files because there should be warning messages which will point out the problem in your code.  For example, on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/MV3p), I see this warning:

```
Warning-[PCWM-W] Port connection width mismatch
testbench.sv, 21
"four_bit_adder adder(x, y, carry_in, sum, carry_out);"
  The following 1-bit expression is connected to 4-bit port "sum" of module 
  "four_bit_adder", instance "adder".
  Expression: sum
  Instantiated module defined at: "testbench.sv", 8
```

The warning goes away when you change:

```
  wire sum;
```

to:

```
  wire [0:3] sum;
```

---

You can use `wait`, but you should account for the situation when the expression is never true.  In this case, you could add a testbench timeout which ends the simulation cleanly after a reasonable amount of time.  For example, add a second `initial` block in `four_bit_adder_test`:

```
initial begin
    #50 $display("Error: timeout");
    $finish;
end
```